# What Is Actually MD5?

Tags: md5, code

Every time i want to download some softwares , it always told about the MD5 below the description or below the download file

for the example : https://anonymous-proxy-servers.net/en/jondo.html
it has a code that i don't understand like : MD5: 33c8290b4e1fd691685da7cfd6e38115

what exactly is the function of the MD5?

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) explains it pretty well:

> The MD5 message-digest algorithm is a widely used cryptographic hash function producing a 128-bit (16-byte) hash value, typically expressed in text format as a 32 digit hexadecimal number. MD5 has been utilized in a wide variety of cryptographic applications, and is also commonly used to verify data integrity.

So, MD5 can calculate a (somewhat) unique number to verify if a file's integrety is OK and if there wasn't any tampering and/or data corruption.

Comment: It's also commonly used to encrypt users' passwords in databases, which is iron because it's easily broken. Many free SQL Injection tools like Havij and even webapps have MD5 crackers.